# JPanel problem - repaint on resize on normal look

Tags: java, swing, svg, batik

I have strange problem with JPanel. I am trying to show svg image ( SVG_class extends JSVGCanvas from batik jar). Problem is when I start this program I get this

[image]

and when I resize with pointer frame a little I get normal picture like this

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.apache.batik.swing.JSVGCanvas;

public class Main {

static JScrollPane scrollpane;
// The frame.
protected JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {

final JFrame f = new JFrame("frame");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(700, 500);
f.setBackground(Color.blue);

SVG_class svg = new SVG_class();
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
p.add(svg);
p.setBackground(Color.red);
scrollpane = new JScrollPane(p);
scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));

Container cont = f.getContentPane();
cont.add(scrollpane);

f.setVisible(true);
}

}

public class SVG_class extends JSVGCanvas {
private List<Type> list;
private int rad;
public boolean red_dot(int iX, int iY, String sX, String sY){
boolean b;
int x,y;
x=Math.abs(iX-(int)Double.parseDouble(sX));
y=Math.abs(iY-(getSize().height-(int)Double.parseDouble(sY)));
System.out.println("iX="+iX+" iY="+iY+" sX="+sX+" sY="+sY+" x="+x+" y="+y);
b=(x<=rad) &&(y<=rad);
return b;
}

    public SVG_class(){
    try {
    this.list=CSV.getCSV("map2");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String fileName = "map2";
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Gigabyte\\Desktop\\SVG\\"+fileName+".svg");
    try {
    this.setURI(file.toURL().toString());
                this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    //
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    boolean found=false;
    // System.out.println("pritisnuo si x="+e.getX()+" y="+e.getY());
    int x,y;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size() && !found;i++ ){
    found=red_dot(e.getX(), e.getY(), list.get(i).getX(), list.get(i).getY());
    }
    if (found) {
    System.out.println("pritisao!!!!");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    }
    });
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Can someone tell me what is mistake ? I tried with p.repaint but it didn't help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  See if you can reproduce the result by replacing the SVG rendering component using a colored panel.

Answer (score 3):

Posting the source for `SVG_class` might make it easier to see what the problem is.

As it is, I suspect the problem is because you're not explicitly telling it what kind of layout to use.

If you want `svg` to take up the whole window you could do `p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));` after you create `p`.

Comment: I don't have size in constructor

Comment: Which constructor are you referring to? Have you tried actually specifying a layout manager to see if it helps?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `f.setSize(700, 500);` just before showing.

Answer (score 1):

`SVG_class` has probably set its size in the constructor. Don't do that and define the size at after calling the constructor.

EDIT: Try adding

```
f.pack();
```